# No pubspec.lock, o que é uma dependência "direct main"?

Tags: dart, convenções-de-nome

No Dart, especificamos dependências através do `pubspec.yaml` através de indicadores da versão desejada (semelhante ao `gemfile` para Ruby ou o `composer.json` para PHP). A partir dessa lista de dependências e versões, o próprio SDK do Dart trabalha para compilar essas informações para o que **está de fato usando**, no momento. O resultado dessa compilação é o arquivo `pubspec.lock`.

É recomendado (pela [documentação do próprio Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/private-files)), em bibliotecas, não submeter esse arquivo para o sistema de versões; em compensação, para **aplicações**, a recomendação é *subir* esse arquivo, de tal modo que todos os desenvolvedores peguem a mesma dependência naquele ponto de código.

Fazendo manutenção em uma aplicação, notei que houve uma mudança no `pubspec.lock`: uma dependência deixou de ser "*transitive*" para ser "*direct main*".

> [Exemplo de dependência *transitive*/*direct main*](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/blob/ff816f277b3833dfdf876663da9a5b8bf6414ecb/pubspec.lock#L4-L12):
>
> ```
> packages:
>   _fe_analyzer_shared:
>     dependency: transitive
>     description:
>       name: _fe_analyzer_shared
>       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
>     source: hosted
>     version: "1.0.0"
>   analyzer:
>     dependency: "direct main"
>     description:
>       name: analyzer
>       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
>     source: hosted
>     version: "0.39.1"
> ```

Minha questão é: o que difere uma dependência *transitive* de uma *direct main*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vamos supor que em seu `pubspec.yaml` você deixe claro a necessidade de duas dependências:

```
Dependencia_A: '<3.0.0'
Dependencia_B: '<3.0.0'
```

Significa que essas duas dependências são necessárias [diretamente](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/glossary#immediate-dependency) pelo seu código. Você requisitou e sua instalação foi marcada como necessária por você.

Dependências desse tipo vão ser marcadas como `direct main`.

Agora, supondo que a `Dependencia_A` necessite também da `Dependencia_C`, essa dependência também deverá ser instalada, porém ela teve origem [transitiva](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/glossary#transitive-dependency). Isto é, não é uma dependência direta de seu código.

Dependências desse tipo vão ser marcadas como `transitive`.

Do site que linkei, traduzido livremente:

> Se seu pacote depende de A, que por sua vez depende de B, que depende de C, então A é uma dependência imediata enquanto B e C são dependências transitivas.